# Array an object along a 3d spline without massive distortion

Tags: bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I'm extruding a mesh along a flat bezier curve using Array (fixed count) and then a Curve modifier.

[image: object array along bezier curve]

So far so good. When I move the points of the spline along the X and Y the object reacts accordingly. However, if I move any of the points on the Z axis, the object is horribly distorted and unusable.

[image: model distorted along z axis]

How do I get around this?
[File attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wSA7BsGQ4W82L5j0enlFdBEOrq4D_vUy/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello could you please share your file?

Comment: @moonboots Updated with link to file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the scale of your curve, then switch to *Edit* mode, select all the vertices and right click > *Set Curve Radius* > type 1 (because if you've scaled the curve then applied, it has changed the vertices radius).